# Old black and white Sci-Fi TV show episode where one person whispers something in someone's ear and then that immediately person does the same

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was very young in the late 70s or early 80s I remember watching an old black and white television program episode (probably the Twilight Zone or something similar) where one person whispered something in someone's ear and then that person's eyes glazed over and then he or she went and whispered something in another person's ear and the same thing kept happening.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this somehow brainwashing the people or something?  What happened to them after they were brainwashed?

Comment: There's an episode of the second *Twilight Zone* series (1985) called "Need to Know" with a very similar plot, but it's too late and not black-and-white.

Comment: Unless he had a B&W tv in 1985 - which i did (dadnabit)

Comment: It seemed to be set in the 1950s or 1960s (I was born in 1976).  Think about the most basic meme in the world.  A man comes home with a blank stare on his face.  He walks up to his wife and then whispers something into her ear.  She then immediately has the same expression and then goes up to someone else and the exact same thing happens.